# Подсчет чисел Фибоначчи без использования букв в исходном коде

Tags: c

В университете дали задание реализовать консольное приложение, выводящее число фибоначчи по его номеру (номер задается через аргументы командной строки) с таким условием: В исходном коде приложения не должно быть никаких букв. С подсчетом числа проблем не возникло, собственно вот:

```
__$(_)

{
    ___ = !_ ? 0 : _ == -1 || _ == 1 ? 1 : _ > 0 ? __$(_ - 1) + __$(_ - 2) : 
__$(_ + 2) - __$(_ + 1);
}
```

Проблема в том, что я не имею абсолютно никакого представления о том, как конвертировать аргумент командной строки из const char ** в int и как осуществить вывод на экран получившегося значения с учетом поставленного условия

Comment: Думаю не у меня одного возникнет вопрос нахзачем

Comment: Тот же самый вопрос возник и у меня, но задание есть задание, приходится делать

Comment: а кто сказал, что номер нужно именно числом задавать? можно звездочками. Так как где то 46-48 число уже превышает int32/uint32. Набить 40 звездочек - вполне возможно. И я бы рекурсивный алгоритм как выше не использовал бы - лучше итерациями.

Comment: Но мы должны хотя бы тип аргумента main написать. Это невозможно.

Comment: int main(int !_, char **!__) {

Comment: Или включить макросы, где printf будет заменен какой-нибудь небуквенной последовательностью.

Comment: По поводу макросов, имеется в виду #define? Если да, то так, к сожалению, тоже нельзя сделать(

Comment: Либо вы не совсем правильно поняли задание, либо речь не про Си.

Comment: никто не мешает объявить main вот так `main($,$_)` и в `$` будет кол-во аргументов, переданное с командной строки. И вызвать приложение можно будет где то так './fib 1 1 1`, что бы получить там 4.

Comment: Есть достаточно  нетрадиционный способ решить эту проблему. Для начала читаем статью http://jroweboy.github.io/c/asm/2015/01/26/when-is-main-not-a-function.html и узнаем, что main - это не обязательно функция. Точнее, не функция в понимании прикладного программиста.